# Synchronization within a multi-threaded operation contract

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, thread-safety, task

Following operation contract constructs and return an de-serialized data structure called `ObjectGraph`. This is accomplished through

- Step (**a**) retrieving an object id using logged in user. This ensures no two user get same object id.
- Step (**b**) uses the object id (from Step **a**) to load the serialized object graph.

At this stage, both steps **a** and **b** are performed within a synchronized block using `lock`. This works as expected. However, I now want to split Step **a** and **b** separately due to performance concern as Step **b** takes comparatively longer than Step a and hence clients get queued-up easily.

Is it possible to split without loosing the synchronized access? If so, does someone know how ?

```
[ErrorBehavior(typeof(ErrorHandler))]
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class ServiceImp : IService
{
    private static object _lockOb = new object();
    //ObjectGraph is a custom data structure.
    public ObjectGraph GetObject(Guid IdUser)
    {
        lock(_lockOb) //This is to ensure that no two or more client execute below logic at any point in time.
        {
            //GetId method returns object id from database.
            var id=GetId(); 

            //LoadObjectGraphFromDatabase accept object id, read serialized data from database and finally returns a de-serialized ObjectGraph object.
            var graph=LoadObjectGraphFromDatabase(id) 
            return graph;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's stopping another process altering the graph with Id in database?

Comment: A question like this is probably more suited to [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: How could you split a and b? b depends on a - it needs the id returned from a. Also why are you mucking around with locks in the method, just let WCF manage that via concurrency mode.

Comment: @MitchWheat, If i get it correct, I am switching a lock flag (db column) once an object id is been dispatched.

Comment: @Nair: that made no sense to me.

Comment: @EricScherrer, Step a is must faster when compare step b. So the idea is to separate these steps. Something like, send the Id (from step a) to a independent method load the object graph.

Comment: @MitchWheat, What is not making sense to you ? Can you advice ?